# Mapping list of objects in a linear fashion

Tags: java, list, loops, java-stream, mapping

Consider two objects, namely

```
Person -> name, age, salary, address, sqFootage

House  -> address, sqFootage
```

which contain the given parameters.

I need to map the data from a list of houses (List) to the list of people (List) . The condition is that person 1  owns the only first house, and the first house belongs only to the first person, i.e: one to one mapping. I'm trying to enhance the logic I've written. What other ways could I try the following code?

```
for(int i =0; i<personList.size(); i++){
    for( int j = 0; j<houseList.size(); j++){
        if( i == j){
            personList.get(i).setAddress(houseList.get(j).getAddress);
            personList.get(i).setSqFootage(houseList.get(j).getSqFootage)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you've posted? Is something not working as intended?

Comment: where is the context around `sqFootage` used in the code?

Comment: It is working exactly as intended. However, I'm trying to look for ways that are more elegant that my solution.

Comment: It was a typo. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using unnecessary nested loop. If the person with index 1 owns the house with index 1, `personList` and `houseList` have the same size, you can do it with using one for loop, or  you can use an `IntStream` to iterate over the required range `(0,  personList.size())`:

```
IntStream.range(0,  personList.size()).forEach(i -> { 
    personList.get(i).setAddress(houseList.get(i).getAddress());
    personList.get(i).setSqFootage(houseList.get(i).getSqFootage());
});
```

With nested for loop in the question:

```
e.g. 3 person - 3 houses

person      house
0           0   // if( i == j) -> true, assign house(0) to person(0)
0           1   // unnecessary step
0           2   // ...
1           0   // ...
1           1   // if( i == j) -> true, assign house(1) to person(1)
1           2   // unnecessary step
2           0   // ...
2           1   // ...
2           2   // if( i == j) -> true, assign house(2) to person(2)
```

So you loop 9 times, but assign a house to a person just 3 times.

Comment: Thanks a lot for educating me about IntStream. This solution is cleaner to look at.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, don't think you need a nested loop (because there is a one-to-one mapping), so something like this should work:

```
for(int i =0; i<personList.size(); i++){
    personList.get(i).setAddress(houseList.get(i).getAddress());
    personList.get(i).setSqFootage(houseList.get(i).getSqFootage());
}
```